# Kotlin BuildType 'XYZ': id 'XYZ' is already used in BuildType(uuid='', id='XYZ', name='Deploy to envr') error

Tags: kotlin, teamcity, devops, kotlin-dsl, configuration-as-code

I was trying to refactor my Kotlin file that contains the configuration for a TeamCity pipeline. However, I keep getting the following error:

*BuildType 'KotlinExperiments_DeployToEnvironment': id 'KotlinExperiments_DeployToEnvironment' is already used in BuildType(uuid='', id='KotlinExperiments_DeployToEnvironment', name='Deploy to test')*

I tried to [dynamically assign an ID](https://github.com/ClydeDz/kotlin-experiments/blob/0bd0de1d083aaeadf46b100490fa1c6ce9d3535f/.teamcity/_buildTypes/DeployToEnvironment.kt#L12-L13), but that doesn't seem to work. Here are the links to the relevant files:

- [.teamcity/settings.kts](https://github.com/ClydeDz/kotlin-experiments/blob/0bd0de1d083aaeadf46b100490fa1c6ce9d3535f/.teamcity/settings.kts)
- [.teamcity/KotlinExperiments.kt](https://github.com/ClydeDz/kotlin-experiments/blob/0bd0de1d083aaeadf46b100490fa1c6ce9d3535f/.teamcity/KotlinExperiments.kt)
- [.teamcity/_buildTypes/DeployToEnvironment.kt](https://github.com/ClydeDz/kotlin-experiments/blob/0bd0de1d083aaeadf46b100490fa1c6ce9d3535f/.teamcity/_buildTypes/DeployToEnvironment.kt)

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

It appears that there was an extra `}` in [this line](https://github.com/ClydeDz/kotlin-experiments/blob/0bd0de1d083aaeadf46b100490fa1c6ce9d3535f/.teamcity/_buildTypes/DeployToEnvironment.kt#L12) which is an invalid character for an ID. TeamCity didn't really provide an accurate error. After deleting the whole and recreating it again, TeamCity provided a much better error which led me to this finding.